Problem of basic fluid statics
Consider a setup where a fish tank filled with water up to some level is kept on a weighing scale. The weight of the setup including the tank and the water is W₁. Then, a fish of weight, say, W₂ is introduced into the system. What will be the reading on the weighing scale now?
Would appreciate a conceptual explanation for this problem, since I am new to this topic.

Water + Tank system weighs W1. When the fish is introduced, the weight reading should increase. If the fish is in equilibrium(not accelerating in vertical direction), then you can say Water + Tank + Fish system should have net force 0 acting on it. Since gravitational force is W1+W2, then normal force(weight scale force) must be W1+W2.
Another way to think of it is that fish has W2 weight, but it is not falling down in the water. This means that the water exerts a force upwards on the fish and the force will cancel out the gravitational force(W2). Hence, extra force exerted by water on the fish is W2, which means the fish exerts W2 force on water downwards. To compensate for this, the scale will exert an additional W2 force upwards on water. Hence, net force exerted by scale is W1+W2
Yet another way to think about this is that when you put the fish in the water, the water level will rise by some height 'H'. Now, additional pressure exerted by water at the bottom will be '$\rho$gH', Hence net increase in force will be '$\rho$gHA' where A is the Area of base of tank. '$\rho$gHA' if you observe carefully is the weight of water displaced by the fish, which means this weight is the force of buoyancy which is W2. So, extra force exerted by weight scale is W2.
